# Passing parameter into sql string triple with using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val BusinessDate = '2019-02-06'
val query = """(SELECT *
                  |FROM
                  |  v_Account AS a left join v_Customer AS c
                  | ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND c.Businessdate = a.Businessdate
                  |WHERE
                  | a.Category = 'Deposit' AND
                  | c.Businessdate= '2019-02-06' AND a.Balance IS NOT NULL AND
                  | isnull(a.Classification,'N/A') IN ('Contractual Account','Non-Term Deposit','Term Deposit')) tmp """.stripMargin

val responseWithSelectedColumns = spark
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("dbtable", query)
      .load()

    print("TOTAL: "+responseWithSelectedColumns.count())
```

at this line of sql string `c.Businessdate= '2019-02-06'`, 
I want to pass BusinessDate as parameter instead of direct like this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) in Scala:

```
val BusinessDate = '2019-02-06'
val query = s"""(SELECT *
                  |FROM
                  |  v_Account AS a left join v_Customer AS c
                  | ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND c.Businessdate = a.Businessdate
                  |WHERE
                  | a.Category = 'Deposit' AND
                  | c.Businessdate= '$BusinessDate' AND a.Balance IS NOT NULL AND
                  | isnull(a.Classification,'N/A') IN ('Contractual Account','Non-Term Deposit','Term Deposit')) tmp """.stripMargin
```